# Modify function to return dataframe with specified values

Tags: python, pandas

With reference to the test data below and the function I use to identify values within variable `thresh` of each other.

Can anyone please help me modify this to show the desired output I have shown?

**Test data**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
       {'AAA' : [4,5,6,7,9,10], 
        'BBB' : [10,20,30,40,11,10],
        'CCC' : [100,50,25,10,10,11],
        'DDD' : [98,50,25,10,10,11],
        'EEE' : [103,50,25,10,10,11]});
```

**Function**:

```
thresh = 5    
def closeCols2(df):
        max_value = None
        for k1,k2 in combinations(df.keys(),2):
            if abs(df[k1] - df[k2]) < thresh:
                if max_value is None:
                    max_value = max(df[k1],df[k2])
                else:
                    max_value = max(max_value, max(df[k1],df[k2]))
        return max_value
```

**Data Before function applied:**

```
    AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE
0   4   10  100 98  103
1   5   20  50  50  50
2   6   30  25  25  25
3   7   40  10  10  10
4   9   11  10  10  10
5   10  10  11  11  11
```

**Current series output after applied:**

```
df2.apply(closeCols2, axis=1)

0    103
1     50
2     25
3     10
4     11
5     11
dtype: int64
```

**Desired output** is a dataframe showing all values within `thresh` and a `nan` for any not within thresh

```
    AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE
0   nan nan 100 98  103
1   nan nan 50  50  50
2   nan 30  25  25  25
3   7   nan 10  10  10
4   9   11  10  10  10
5   10  10  11  11  11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `mask` and `sub` with `axis=1`

```
df2.mask(df2.sub(df2.apply(closeCols2, 1), 0).abs() > thresh)

    AAA   BBB  CCC  DDD  EEE
0   NaN   NaN  100   98  103
1   NaN   NaN   50   50   50
2   NaN  30.0   25   25   25
3   7.0   NaN   10   10   10
4   9.0  11.0   10   10   10
5  10.0  10.0   11   11   11
```

---

***note:***
I'd redefine `closeCols` to include `thresh` as a parameter.  Then you could pass it in the `apply` call.

```
def closeCols2(df, thresh):
        max_value = None
        for k1,k2 in combinations(df.keys(),2):
            if abs(df[k1] - df[k2]) < thresh:
                if max_value is None:
                    max_value = max(df[k1],df[k2])
                else:
                    max_value = max(max_value, max(df[k1],df[k2]))
        return max_value 

df2.apply(closeCols2, 1, thresh=5)
```

---

***extra credit***
I vectorized and embedded your `closeCols` for some mind numbing fun.
Notice there is no `apply`

- `numpy` **broadcasting** to get all combinations of columns subtracted from each other.
- `np.abs`
- `<= 5`
- `sum(-1)` I arranged the **broadcasting** such that the difference of say row `0`, column `AAA` with all of row `0` will be laid out across the last dimension.  `-1` in the `sum(-1)` says to sum across last dimension.
- `<= 1` all values are less than 5 away from themselves.  So I want the sum of these to be greater than 1.  Thus, we mask all less than or equal to one.

---

```
v = df2.values
df2.mask((np.abs(v[:, :, None] - v[:, None]) <= 5).sum(-1) <= 1)

    AAA   BBB  CCC  DDD  EEE
0   NaN   NaN  100   98  103
1   NaN   NaN   50   50   50
2   NaN  30.0   25   25   25
3   7.0   NaN   10   10   10
4   9.0  11.0   10   10   10
5  10.0  10.0   11   11   11
```

Comment: @adele I've updated my answer.  You may find the new information useful.  However, it may also be difficult to follow.

Comment: Thanks again this is great!  I was also looking at your "path-dependent-slicing" code.  Before I spend too much time trying to learn what you have done, do you think it is potentially useful for profit target analysis financial data?  i.e. could it be used for seeing if a stop loss or profit target is hit first on a simple trading strategy?

Comment: Short answer... yes!

Comment: Well done with creating a new axis and broadcasting to get all the combos.