# count how many elements in a numpy array are within delta of every other element

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy

consider the array `x` and delta variable `d`

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
x = np.random.randint(100, size=10)
d = 10
```

For each element in `x`, I want to count how many other elements in each are within delta `d` *distance* away.

So x looks like

```
print(x)

[11 98 74 90 15 55 13 11 13 26]
```

The results should be

```
[5 2 1 2 5 1 5 5 5 1]
```

---

***what I've tried***
Strategy:

- Use broadcasting to take the outer difference
- Absolute value of outer difference
- sum how many exceed threshold

---

```
(np.abs(x[:, None] - x) <= d).sum(-1)

[5 2 1 2 5 1 5 5 5 1]
```

---

This works great.  However, it doesn't scale.  That outer difference is O(n^2) time.  How can I get the same solution that doesn't scale with quadratic time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Listed in this post are two more *variants* based on the `searchsorted strategy` from [`OP's answer post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41394596/3293881).

```
def pir3(a,d):  # Short & less efficient
    sidx = a.argsort()
    p1 = a.searchsorted(a+d,'right',sorter=sidx)
    p2 = a.searchsorted(a-d,sorter=sidx)
    return p1 - p2

def pir4(a, d):   # Long & more efficient
    s = a.argsort()

    y = np.empty(s.size,dtype=np.int64)
    y[s] = np.arange(s.size)

    a_ = a[s]
    return (
        a_.searchsorted(a_ + d, 'right')
        - a_.searchsorted(a_ - d)
    )[y]
```

The more efficient approach derives the efficient idea to get `s.argsort()` from [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41242285/3293881).

Runtime test -

```
In [155]: # Inputs
     ...: a = np.random.randint(0,1000000,(10000))
     ...: d = 10


In [156]: %timeit pir2(a,d) #@ piRSquared's post solution
     ...: %timeit pir3(a,d)
     ...: %timeit pir4(a,d)
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 2.43 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 4.44 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.66 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  I've updated my testing results to include these variants and extended out the size of the array.

Comment: @piRSquared Those make sense. With smaller arrays the overhead in `pir4` to create the range array for getting `s.argsort()` makes it less worthy than simply sorting. Good thought on your part on getting to use `searchsorted` for this counting problem!

Answer (score 1):

***Strategy***

- Since `x` is not necessarily sorted, we'll sort it and track the sorting permutation via `argsort` so we can reverse the permutation.
- We'll use `np.searchsorted` on `x` with `x - d` to find the starting place for when values of `x` start to exceed `x - d`.
- Do it again on the other side except we'll have to use the `np.searchsorted` parameter `side='right'` and using `x + d`
- Take the difference between right and left searchsorts to calculate number of elements that are within +/- d of each element
- Use argsort to reverse the sorting permutation

---

define method presented in question as `pir1`

```
def pir1(a, d):
    return (np.abs(a[:, None] - a) <= d).sum(-1)
```

We'll define a new function `pir2`

```
def pir2(a, d):
    s = x.argsort()
    a_ = a[s]
    return (
        a_.searchsorted(a_ + d, 'right')
        - a_.searchsorted(a_ - d)
    )[s.argsort()]
```

---

***demo***

```
pir1(x, d)

[5 2 1 2 5 1 5 5 5 1]
```

---

```
pir1(x, d)

[5 2 1 2 5 1 5 5 5 1]
```

---

***timing***
`pir2` is the clear winner!

***code***

*functions*

```
def pir1(a, d):
    return (np.abs(a[:, None] - a) <= d).sum(-1)

def pir2(a, d):
    s = x.argsort()
    a_ = a[s]
    return (
        a_.searchsorted(a_ + d, 'right')
        - a_.searchsorted(a_ - d)
    )[s.argsort()]

#######################
# From Divakar's post #
#######################
def pir3(a,d):  # Short & less efficient
    sidx = a.argsort()
    p1 = a.searchsorted(a+d,'right',sorter=sidx)
    p2 = a.searchsorted(a-d,sorter=sidx)
    return p1 - p2

def pir4(a, d):   # Long & more efficient
    s = a.argsort()

    y = np.empty(s.size,dtype=np.int64)
    y[s] = np.arange(s.size)

    a_ = a[s]
    return (
        a_.searchsorted(a_ + d, 'right')
        - a_.searchsorted(a_ - d)
    )[y]
```

---

*test*

```
from timeit import timeit

results = pd.DataFrame(
    index=np.arange(1, 50),
    columns=['pir%s' %i for i in range(1, 5)])

for i in results.index:
    np.random.seed([3,1415])
    x = np.random.randint(1000000, size=i)
    for j in results.columns:
        setup = 'from __main__ import x, {}'.format(j)
        results.loc[i, j] = timeit('{}(x, 10)'.format(j), setup=setup, number=10000)

results.plot()
```

[image]

---

*extended out to larger arrays*
got rid of `pir1`

```
from timeit import timeit

results = pd.DataFrame(
    index=np.arange(1, 11) * 1000,
    columns=['pir%s' %i for i in range(2, 5)])

for i in results.index:
    np.random.seed([3,1415])
    x = np.random.randint(1000000, size=i)
    for j in results.columns:
        setup = 'from __main__ import x, {}'.format(j)
        results.loc[i, j] = timeit('{}(x, 10)'.format(j), setup=setup, number=100)

results.insert(0, 'pir1', 0)

results.plot()
```

[image]