# Identify clusters linked by delta to the left and different delta to the right

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Consider the sorted array `a`:

```
a = np.array([0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 11, 14, 19, 20, 20])
```

If I specified left and right deltas,

```
delta_left, delta_right = 1, 1
```

Then this is how I'd expect the clusters to be assigned:

```
#   a = [ 0  .  2  3  4  5  .  .  .  . 10 11  .  . 14  .  .  .  . 19 20
#                                         11                         20
#
#                                     [10--|-12]                 [19--|-21]
#           [1--|--3]                 [10--|-12]                 [19--|-21]
#    [-1--|--1]   [3--|--5]         [9--|-11]                 [18--|-20]
#   +--+--|--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--|
#              [2--|--4]                       [13--|-15]
#
#         │    ╰──┬───╯                 ╰┬─╯        │              ╰┬─╯
#         │   cluster 2                Cluster 3    │           Cluster 5
#     Cluster 1                                 Cluster 4
```

***NOTE:*** Despite the interval `[-1, 1]` sharing an edge with `[1, 3]`, neither interval includes an adjacent point and therefore do not constitute joining their respective clusters.

Assuming the cluster assignments were stored in an array named `clusters`, I'd expect the results to look like this

```
print(clusters)
[1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 5 5 5]
```

---

However, suppose I change the left and right deltas to be different:

```
delta_left, delta_right = 2, 1
```

This means that for a value of `x` it should be combined with any other point in the interval `[x - 2, x + 1]`

```
#   a = [ 0  .  2  3  4  5  .  .  .  . 10 11  .  . 14  .  .  .  . 19 20
#                                         11                         20
#
#                                   [9-----|-12]              [18-----|-21]
#        [0-----|--3]               [9-----|-12]              [18-----|-21]
# [-2-----|--1][2-----|--5]      [8-----|-11]              [17-----|-20]
#   +--+--|--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--|
#           [1 ----|--4]                    [12-----|-15]
#
#         ╰─────┬─────╯                 ╰┬─╯        │              ╰┬─╯
#           cluster 1                Cluster 2      │           Cluster 4
#                                               Cluster 3
```

***NOTE:*** Despite the interval `[9, 12]` sharing an edge with `[12, 15]`, neither interval includes an adjacent point and therefore do not constitute joining their respective clusters.

Assuming the cluster assignments were stored in an array named `clusters`, I'd expect the results to look like this:

```
print(clusters)
[1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 4 4 4]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We will leverage [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) and logic to find cluster edges.

First, let's take a closer look at what `np.searchsorted` does:

> Find the indices into a sorted array a such that, if the corresponding elements in v were inserted before the indices, the order of a would be preserved.

What I'll do is execute `np.searchsorted` with `a` using `a - delta_left`.  Let's look at that for `delta_left = 1`

```
# a =
# [ 0  2  3  4  5 10 11 11 14 19 20 20]
# 
# a - delta_left
# [-1  1  2  3  4  9 10 10 13 18 19 19]
```

- `-1` would get inserted at position `0` to maintain order
- `1` would get inserted at position `1` to maintain order
- `2` would get inserted at position `1` as well, indicating that `2` might be in the same cluster as `1`
- `3` would get inserted at position `2` indicating that `3` might be in the same cluster as `2`
- so on and so forth

What we notice is that only when an element less delta would get inserted at its current position would we consider a new cluster starting.

We do this again for the right side with a difference.  The difference is that by default if a bunch of elements are the same, `np.searchsorted` assumes to insert into the front of values.  To identify the ends of clusters, I'm going to want to insert after the identical elements.  Therefore I'll use the paramater `side='right'`

> If ‘left’, the index of the first suitable location found is given. If ‘right’, return the last such index. If there is no suitable index, return either 0 or N (where N is the length of a).

Now the logic.  A cluster can only begin if a prior cluster has ended, with the exception of the first cluster.  We'll then consider a shifted version of the results of our second `np.searchsorted`

---

Let's now define our function

```
def delta_cluster(a, dleft, dright):
    # use to track whether searchsorted results are at correct positions
    rng = np.arange(len(a))

    edge_left = a.searchsorted(a - dleft)
    starts = edge_left == rng

    # we append 0 to shift
    edge_right = np.append(0, a.searchsorted(a + dright, side='right')[:-1])
    ends = edge_right == rng

    return (starts & ends).cumsum()
```

---

***demonstration***

with left, right deltas equal to 1 and 1

```
print(delta_cluster(a, 1, 1))

[1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 5 5 5]
```

with left, right deltas equal to 2 and 1

```
print(delta_cluster(a, 2, 1))

[1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 4 4 4]
```

***Extra Credit***
What if `a` isn't sorted?
I'll utilize information learned from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41394595/2336654)

```
def delta_cluster(a, dleft, dright):

    s = a.argsort()

    size = s.size

    if size > 1000:
        y = np.empty(s.size, dtype=np.int64)
        y[s] = np.arange(s.size)
    else:
        y = s.argsort()

    a = a[s]

    rng = np.arange(len(a))

    edge_left = a.searchsorted(a - dleft)
    starts = edge_left == rng

    edge_right = np.append(0, a.searchsorted(a + dright, side='right')[:-1])
    ends = edge_right == rng

    return (starts & ends).cumsum()[y]
```

***demonstration***

```
b = np.random.permutation(a)
print(b)

[14 10  3 11 20  0 19 20  4 11  5  2]
```

---

```
print(delta_cluster(a, 2, 1))

[1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 4 4 4]
```

---

```
print(delta_cluster(b, 2, 1))

[3 2 1 2 4 1 4 4 1 2 1 1]
```

---

```
print(delta_cluster(b, 2, 1)[b.argsort()])

[1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 4 4 4]
```